# Animation of pageControl in viewController from nowhere

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9

In my viewController which is the delegate of my scrollView

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    slides = loadSlides()
    setupSlideScrollView(slides: slides)

    pageControl.numberOfPages = slides.count
    pageControl.currentPage = 0
    view.bringSubview(toFront: pageControl)

    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}

func loadSlides() -> [Slide] {

    let slide1: Slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Slide", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Slide
    slide1.quizLabel.text = "This is slide1"
    slide1.hintLabel.text = "yeah"

    let slide2: Slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Slide", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Slide
    slide2.quizLabel.text = "This is slide2"
    slide2.hintLabel.text = "YEAH"

    let slides = [slide1, slide2]
    return slides
}

func setupSlideScrollView(slides : [Slide]) {
    let width = view.frame.width
    let height = view.frame.height
    scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                              y: 0,
                              width: width,
                              height: height)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(slides.count) * width, height: height)
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

    for slide in slides {
        slide.quizLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        slide.quizLabel.font = UIFont(name: (textField.font?.fontName)!, size: 20)

        slide.hintLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        slide.hintLabel.font = UIFont(name: (textField.font?.fontName)!, size: 18)

        slide.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(slides.index(of: slide)!) * width,
                             y: 0,
                             width: width,
                             height: height)
        scrollView.addSubview(slide)
    }
}
```

When running, the pageControl shows up with a sliding animation. It seems it slides from the origin of the view. I have no idea why it comes out like that.

The pageControl is at the top

[image]

My segue settings as followed

[image: My segue settings]

p.s. Also, anyway to solve the similar problem for the sliding labels and the cursor?

I would like to appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: Can you please add `setupSlideScrollView` and `loadSlides`? Impossible to reproduce your problem without that code.

Comment: @regina_fallangi Added.

Comment: Have you tried unchecking "Animates"? Also, where do you set `pageControl`?

Comment: @regina_fallangi Yes I tried but it didn't work. The fading effect was totally gone. I set the pageControl in the storyboard the same level of the scrollView with proper constraints. It is precisely at where the weird sliding animation ends at.